# How can I make my UISearchController show the cells underneath?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have a UITableViewController (with 6 cells) and a UISearchController. Whenever I tap on the search bar, the table view cells disappear and are replaced with an empty tableView until I start typing something and the search results appear. How can I make it so that cells stay underneath when I tap the search bar?
Here is my code pertaining to the SearchController:

In viewDidLoad():

```
self.resultSearchController = ({
            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            controller.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 240/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 1)

            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
            self.definesPresentationContext = true

            return controller
        })()
```

The rest:

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
                return self.filteredTableData.count
            } else {
                return self.items.count
            }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        var item : TextCell

        if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
            item = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        } else {
            item = items[indexPath.row]
            cell.userText.text = item.userText
            cell.userPreferredName.text = item.userPreferredName
            cell.userName.text = item.userName

            cell.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = 23.75
            cell.userImage.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.userImage.layer.borderWidth = 0.3
            cell.userImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
            cell.time.text = "\((indexPath.row + 1) * 3)m"
            return cell
        }

    }
}

extension TableViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }

}

extension TableViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        var filteredArray : [TextCell] = [TextCell]()

        for textCell in self.items
        {
            if (textCell.userName.rangeOfString(searchController.searchBar.text) != nil ||
                textCell.userPreferredName.rangeOfString(searchController.searchBar.text) != nil ||
                textCell.userText.rangeOfString(searchController.searchBar.text) != nil)
            {
                filteredArray.append(textCell)
            }
        }

        filteredTableData = filteredArray

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Screenshots:
[image]

Bonus:
Is there any way of making those cells selectable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the searchText is empty, then set the `filteredTableData` to `items`

```
extension TableViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        var filteredArray : [TextCell] = [TextCell]()

        if searchController.searchBar.text == "" {
            filteredArray = self.items
        } else {
            for textCell in self.items
            {
                if (textCell.userName.rangeOfString(searchController.searchBar.text) != nil ||
                    textCell.userPreferredName.rangeOfString(searchController.searchBar.text) != nil ||
                    textCell.userText.rangeOfString(searchController.searchBar.text) != nil)
                {
                    filteredArray.append(textCell)
                }
            }
        }
        filteredTableData = filteredArray

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is populate the filteredDataArray with no filtering at first, and then apply the filtering as it goes. You aren't setting filteredDataArray to anything until you start searching, so in the start of the search just set it to the full data set.

Bonus:

You can use tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath to catch selection, and this should work even with the search table view.

Comment: what do you mean by the first part?